# Typescript misunderstanding - why are all properties required in a Record?

Tags: typescript, types

In this trivial example:

```
type AllowedKeys = 'a' | 'b'

const someObject: Record<AllowedKeys, boolean> = {a:true, b:false}

const anotherObject:  Record<AllowedKeys, boolean> = {a:true}
```

`someObject` is valid but `anotherObject` is not:

> Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: true; }' but required in type 'Record<AllowedKeys, boolean>'.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Record` basically spreads out the union into discrete properties, like this:

```typescript
{
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}
```

This is shown in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

> ```typescript
> interface CatInfo {
>   age: number;
>   breed: string;
> }
>  
> type CatName = "miffy" | "boris" | "mordred";
>  
> const cats: Record<CatName, CatInfo> = {
>   miffy: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
>   boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" },
>   mordred: { age: 16, breed: "British Shorthair" },
> };
> ```

If you want `a` and `b` to be optional, you can apply [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type AllowedKeys = 'a' | 'b'

const someObject: Partial<Record<AllowedKeys, boolean>> = {a:true, b:false}
//                ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
const anotherObject:  Partial<Record<AllowedKeys, boolean>> = {a:true}
//                    ^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

Now, both are valid.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwNIRAZygXigHIBDIqAH2ICMiAoOgY0QDsdgodEBbCAeWoArCI2AAuKAAUSAJ2ABLEnAA8AJRGIZaZfCSpM2HABoo1RIjgQSLAHw2CUAN4kxwGQFcIJ6mIBmSnAgAXzoAelCoSKjomKgAPQTEhMAkIlS09IzMrLimVnYoa0RgAAsIGQFhUQkpWQUlNQ0tHQQUdCxcb3NLazsHZ1cPYLCI2NHYpKSsqen0nKA)

Comment: Thanks. Are unions are special case? by which I mean, why is `Record<string,boolean>` different?

Comment: With the `string` type, you are not enforcing specific values. But with the union `AllowedKeys` and without `Partial`, you are enforcing all the keys to be in the object. Without `Partial`, a better name for the union would be `RequiredKeys`.

Comment: @WillJenkins - I don't think unions are special (`Record<string | number, boolean>` creates `{ [x: string]: boolean; [x: number]: boolean; }`, an object where any string *or* any number is a valid key), but perhaps literal keys are. After all, `{}` is valid for `Record<string, boolean>` or `Record<string | number, boolean>`, but not `Record<"a" | number, boolean>` (which requires an `a` property). I think it's because `string` and `number` are unbounded, but literals have specific values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah thanks, I was thinking along those lines but hadn't actually played around to test the different variations

Comment: @WillJenkins - My pleasure. I should warn you that my type theory is not strong. :-D